# How can I get an overridden Text property of my user control to show up in the form designer in VS2005?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, user-controls, propertygrid, windows-forms-designer

I have a user control with the following code in it.

```
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Appearance")]
public override string Text { ... }

private int myVar;
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Appearance")]
public int MyProperty { ... }
```

`MyProperty` shows up in the property grid when the control is inserted in a form, but `Text` does not.  How can I get it visible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the System.ComponentModel.Browsable(true) attribute to your property it should show up in the property browser. Using your example above I confirmed the behavior in VS2008.

Comment: Hm.  I've tried this, and it still seems not to be working.  I'll restart VS.  *grumbles*

Comment: I had trouble getting any property to show up but then I realized I was editing MyControl, not the MainForm in which I had placed. That is where the properties are changeable (duh!). Hope that helps anyone who reads this.

Comment: Restarting Visual Studio after adding the Browsable(true) attribute worked for me